# Symfony: Accessing parameters without container or static configured service

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

We have a project we're migrating to Symfony 3.3 and the new DI configuration. We have a service that used to be passed values from parameters file based on an argument supplied to the command. (bit more complex than this but you get the idea):

```
$this->service->setOptions($this->getContainer()->getParameter('account_'.$accountId));
```

With the migration we want to stop making the commands `ContainerAwareCommand` as we can now use new DI for the services. However, this leaves us stuck working out an alternative method of fetching the parameters when we cannot statically configure them in services.yml

Would it be best for me to just use the Yaml component and read the parameters.yml file in manually for this or is there some other, more appropriate solution?

Comment: I assume $accountId is request dependent?  If so then DI is not going to work for you.  I also assume there is a small number of fixed accounts?  Is then I'd suggest defining your account info as a parameter array and just injecting it.  Reading and parsing a yaml file on every request is a bit heavy.  It will slow things up though you might not notice it.

Comment: Since `$accountId` is probably dynamic I would try to build the service without id and then have methods for `doSomethingByAccountId($accountId)` that will be called in your controllers. For example you could create some kind of Factory-service for this, that builds your id-specific services instead of letting the container do it.

Comment: `$accountId` is defined as a command argument. The YAML file contains account specific configuration details for a few services (such as FTP details) and is securely generated so moving the details is not an option. The services cannot do anything without these details but are only used in CLI commands. Also, there are several hundred thousand potential accounts but at the moment, this project is fairly new so we're only at a few hundred using it so far.